# Receiving false email alerts because of the retry configuration enabled for Azure data factory activities

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-monitoring, alerts

We configured azure Monitoring alerts to capture failed activities and its working as expected.

We are receiving a lot of false alert email because we have enabled the "Retry" setting for Azure Data Factory Activities which retries 3 times in the event of failure and succeeds the failed activity.

Is there a we can configure alert only to send alert when activity is actually failed after the last retry attempt..? considering our issue any suggestions would be helpful

tried to check but within the Alert rule don't have any option for customization to configure to ignore alert if failed activity is succeeded in the retry attempt

Comment: what are you using to generate alerts? Built-in adf alerts should have a threshold on activity failure or pipeline failure metric.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ashwin Mohan.
As a workaround, you can try the Azure Logic apps for the failed Pipeline alerts in your data factory and configure the email alert to your outlook.
This is my Idea this may help you.

- Use 2 Set variables activities.
- SET Variable 1 is a bollean as FALSE
- SET Variable 2 assigin the value of it to "0"
- use until activity use the condition like (SET1=="True" or SET 2==3)
- Next the Execute pipeline activity(include your pipeline activities
  with in the execute pipeline activity)
- Here after on success SET variable 1 is set to TRUE
- On failure incrementing SET variable 2 by 1.
- Then we use   IF condition is True SET variable  2 ==3 in True
  condition  and then it should be followed by web acitivity.

Here is web activity using the URL to [Logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email) you can configure your pipeline failure emails.